# Laravel runs scheduled commands without cron job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

I have created some commands and scheduled them to work periodically. A few months later I noticed that there is no cron job running but commands run without problem.

In the documentation, it says that I need to set a cron job in the operating system for scheduled commands to run. I couldn't find any. But artisan `queue:listen` command is run as daemon. Could this command be running the scheduled jobs as well?

Laravel 5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Did you mean this? https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling

Comment: It could be possible that your queue scripts are also running the same methods and functions associated with your scheduled jobs. But it's not possible that your scheduled scripts are running just on their own without CRON - or some other server automation - set up.

Comment: @S.I. Yes, I mean that. But I didn't set a cron job as shown in Starting The Scheduler part.

Comment: @maiorano84 queue and schedule methods aren't related. Somehow schedule runs without problems.

Comment: U mean there is nothing in Crontab file still script is running?

Comment: @kapil.dev I check the crontab file by running `crontab -e`. There are only commented lines.

Comment: I want you to know that "crontab -e" and "sudo crontab -e" are 2 different files.... so check in "sudo crontab -e" as well and let me know.

Comment: @kapil.dev both commands open the same file or their contents are the same. Commented lines only.

Comment: Is there anything listed when you `sudo ls -al /var/spool/cron/crontabs/`?

Comment: If there's too much in there, you might be able to try `sudo grep -rl "artisan" /var/spool/cron/crontabs/`. I haven't tested that myself, but something like that might help.

Comment: @maiorano84 Yes, there is a file named www-data. But I cannot go there with `cd`.

Comment: .... That's why you have `sudo`.

Comment: Run the following and post your results in your question: `sudo cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data`

Comment: @maiorano84 `sudo cd ...` gives the error "command not found". I see there is a cron job entry for artisan. How do I put new cron job or remove them from that file. Edit: `sudo crontab -e -u www-data` does the job I guess. Write those as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Awesome job, dude! I only pointed you in the right direction. It looks like you arrived at the answer yourself. I'll leave an answer up in case others come by with the same question, but if you would like to add your own answer and accept it yourself, feel free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, when a cron job is created, the associated crontab file is generated for each user that ran the actual command. When this particular artisan cron was generated, it was created by the `www-data` user, which was why you couldn't find it as easily.

Each crontab is stored as `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/<username>`, and should be open to something like Grep, or other commands to inspect their contents.

Once you find the correct crontab that needs to be adjusted, you can change the file by running `sudo crontab -e -u <username>`.